# Closing a popup by clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have researched this question and found proposed solutions, but none of them have worked for me. Every solution I find opens and closes the popup immediately.

Essentially, I am just wanting to be able to close the popup window without needing to click "close". If the user clicks outside of `#formWrap` then I am wanting the popup to close.

To see the popup appear without it fading away immediately, remove the line of code below:

`$('#pdfPop').fadeOut(350); //This line here`

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('.pdfWrap').on('click', function (event) {
 $('#pdfPop').fadeIn(350);
 $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});

//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
 var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
 $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
 $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');

 e.preventDefault();
});
/*$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#pdfPop').length){
        $('#pdfPop').fadeOut(350);
    }
});*/
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ( $(event.target).closest('#formWrap').get(0) == null ) {         
   // alert('clicked outside');   
 $('#pdfPop').fadeOut(350); //This line here
    } else{
   // alert('clicked inside');
    }
});
```

```css
#pdfPop {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 color: #FFF;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9999;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 display: none;
}
#popInner {
 position: relative;
}
#xClose {
 position: absolute;
 right: 50px;
 top: 20px;
 width: 33px;
 height: auto;
}
#pdfBlock1 {
 background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #000, #231F20);
 width: 65%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="pdfWrap">Click Me</div>
<div id="pdfPop" data-popup="pop1">
 <div class="popInner">
  <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="pop1" href="#">Close</a>
  <span id="testVal"></span>
  <div id="formWrap" class="total-center">
   <div id="pdfBlock1" class="iblock">
    <p class="blockTW" id="TW">Download your 3D PDF</p>
    <form id="pdfForm" method="POST">
   
     <input type="text" class="input block" id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
   </div><div id="pdfBlock2" class="iblock">
    <input id="pdfButton" class="block" type="submit" value="Download File">
    </form>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree the answer is to `stopPropagation()`.  I do believe that this is because `.pdfWrap` is a div and not an anchor or button.

```js
$('.pdfWrap').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();  //this is the only thing I changed.
  $('#pdfPop').fadeIn(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});

//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
  var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
  $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');

  e.preventDefault();
});
/*$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#pdfPop').length){
        $('#pdfPop').fadeOut(350);
    }
});*/
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('#formWrap').get(0) == null) {
    // alert('clicked outside');   
    $('#pdfPop').fadeOut(350); //This line here
  } else {
    // alert('clicked inside');
  }
});
```

```css
#pdfPop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}

#popInner {
  position: relative;
}

#xClose {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 33px;
  height: auto;
}

#pdfBlock1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #000, #231F20);
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pdfWrap">Click Me</div>
<div id="pdfPop" data-popup="pop1">
  <div class="popInner">
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="pop1" href="#">Close</a>
    <span id="testVal"></span>
    <div id="formWrap" class="total-center">
      <div id="pdfBlock1" class="iblock">
        <p class="blockTW" id="TW">Download your 3D PDF</p>
        <form id="pdfForm" method="POST">

          <input type="text" class="input block" id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
      </div>
      <div id="pdfBlock2" class="iblock">
        <input id="pdfButton" class="block" type="submit" value="Download File">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just use `stopPropagation`:

```
$('.pdfWrap').on('click', function (event) {
    $('#pdfPop').fadeIn(350);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});


$('body, [data-popup-close]').on('click', function() {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');

    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#pdfPop').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```